# CSS Style both Current and Children Elements

Tags: html, css, sass

Is there a way to CSS Style Both Current Element and Children elements?

This does it for Current element.

```
.test
{
   color: red;
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 12px;
}
```

This will do for Descendant Children element with class .test.

```
.test *
{
   color: red;
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 12px;
}
```

How do I pick both Current And descendant children element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are not more information about your concrete project structure ...

Just staying in your code you can do:

```
.test,
.test *
{
   color: red;
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Note: using `*` is maybe not the best practice at all as it styles EVERY element (in htis case all children even second, third ... level below `.test`). To avoid that you can do:

```
.test,
.test > *
{  
   ... your code 
}

// or better more specific
// use the tag-name of the direct childs
// in this case I take 'div' as example

.test,
.test > div {
   ... your code
}
```